# Does Apache Freemarker support xlsx?

Tags: excel, ms-office, freemarker

Cant find anything about it in [their](https://freemarker.apache.org/)  documentation. They state that they support xml, but they doesn't mention openxml based document formats.

On the top of that I couldnt manage to create mergefields in excel as the same way I was able to do it in docx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeMarker doesn't care what kind of XML that is. XML is just a tree of nodes as far as it's concerned. It's a low level thing.

Comment: Actually, don't you think xlsx is not an XML format? It's actually XML wrapped in some sort of compression. Meaning, that even if Freemarker is able to generate its XML contents, it still does not result in a proper XLSX file.